# How to merge multiple images from CNN prediction into one image?

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, transpose

I use CNN in Keras to build a model and now I want to use all the images to make the final prediction.
This is the dimensions of my inputs and labels:

```
X_pred, y_pred=next(pred_generator)
X_pred.shape, y_pred.shape
```

result:

```
((132, 64, 64, 3), (132, 64, 64, 1))
```

This is the code for prediction:

```
pred_64= model.predict(X_pred)
pred_64.shape
```

result:

```
(132, 64, 64, 1)
```

As it is obvious, there 132 predicted images with the size of 64X64.
I want to merge every 4 images to create individual image with the size of 128X128. Finally, I should have 33 images by merging every 4 images produced from model.predict.

This is an example about the order of images when they are saved in 128X128 dimension.

[image]

After adding the swapaxes code the images will be rotated as below:

```
pred_128 = pred_64.reshape(66, 128, 64, 1).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(33, 128, 128, 1)
```

[image]

I added `np.transpose` as below. It helps to correct the rotation but image 2 replaced image 3 and vice versa. Could you please help me to solve that?

```
pred_128 = pred_64.reshape(66, 128, 64, 1).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(33, 128, 128, 1)
pred_128= np.transpose(pred_128, [0, 2, 1, 3])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still hope we can fix the problem using reshapes, but in the meantime here is a more brute force solution:

```py
# Initializing counters
i = 0  # Old image number
j = 0  # New image number

# Pre-allocate new images array
pred_128 = np.zeros((33, 128, 128, 1))

# Loop over new images
while j < 33:
    pred_128 [j, :64, :64, 0] = pred_64[0+i, :, :, 0]  # Upper left
    pred_128 [j, :64, 64:, 0] = pred_64[1+i, :, :, 0]  # Upper right
    pred_128 [j, 64:, :64, 0] = pred_64[2+i, :, :, 0]  # Lower left
    pred_128 [j, 64:, 64:, 0] = pred_64[3+i, :, :, 0]  # Lower right

    # Add to counters
    i += 4
    j += 1
```

Comment: @ Jan Willem, You gave a huge help and it works with my images. Is there still any way to solve it with reshape and transpose as mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 1):

You might think reshaping would do the trick, but the ordering is a bit tricky. With a careful `swapaxes` it is possible. The following line will do the trick:

```py
pred_128 = pred_64.reshape(66, 128, 64, 1).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(33, 128, 128, 1)
```

An example illustrating this is given below. Here I first create an array `a` with four different diagonal matrices in it. Then I put them together in the fashion you would like to see an print the result.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((4, 2, 2, 1))
for i in range(0, 4):
    a[i, :, :, 0] = np.eye(2) * (i+1)

b = a.reshape(2, 4, 2, 1).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(1, 4, 4, 1)
print(b[0, :, :, 0])
```

Result:

```py
[[1. 0. 2. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 2.]
 [3. 0. 4. 0.]
 [0. 3. 0. 4.]]
```

Comment: This approach does not correctly merge every 4 images into one. it only duplicates one image into 128X128 dimension. Please see the question. I added an image regarding how the order of images suppose to be in the output. Is there any other method as solution?

Comment: A reshape, if done correctly, should work. A more brute force solution would be iterating over each four input images and concatenate them together. See for example `np.concatenate`

Comment: @Sam to get the reshape working you also need to swap the axes in between of reshaping over each dimension, see my edit.

Comment: @ Jan Willem, thanks for your reply. I think we are close to the answer. After applying the new code, the images were rotated. I put the first 4 original images and the produced image in the question. Please kindly have a look.

Comment: @Sam How does it look with a transpose at the end? I.e. using `pred_128 = pred_64.reshape(66, 128, 64, 1).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(33, 128, 128, 1).T`

Comment: @ Jan Willem, Can you please suggest a solution for this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66365295/how-to-reproduce-merging-multiple-images-by-different-dimensions